# Unable to locate the android sdk flutter

Tags: visual-studio-code, flutter

I installed visual_stdio_code and trying to run "flutter doctor" then this is the error.
and when I run flutter doctor on Command Line and this is answer that I have:

> flutter devices Unable to locate a development device; please run
>   'flutter doctor' for information about installing additional
>   components.

Any help please!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Which folder is it installed? What does your `PATH` and `ANDROID_HOME` environment variables look like?

Comment: Did you install the Android SDK?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9HoW.png

Comment: What do you get when you execute `sdkmanager --version` in the terminal?

Comment: Please also check if `sdk.dir` in your project in `android/local.properies` is correct. When the project was created on your machine, it should be set correctly, if you copied it from somewhere, it might be wrong.

Comment: C:\Users\avinashreddy>sdkmanager
Warning: File C:\Users\avinashreddy\.android\repositories.cfg could not be loaded.
[=======================================] 100% Computing updates...
C:\Users\avinashreddy>

Answer (score 22):

Here's another solution just in case the answer above doesn't work.

Open Android Studio then click on SDK Manager (down-pointing arrow)

This should open a new box with your Android SDK Location at the top. It should look like this:

```
/Users/your-name/Library/Android/sdk
```

Copy that path, head to the Terminal and type this:

```
flutter config --android-sdk /Users/your-name/Library/Android/sdk
```

Next run:

```
flutter doctor --android-licenses
```

You can run `flutter doctor` to verify

That should help.

Comment: In Windows, the path should be "sdk path", for example :"C:\Program Files\Android\android_sdk"

Answer (score 4):

### Step-1

Config the path of android-sdk:

```sh
# use `$ANDROID_HOME` if your android-sdk path is not below
$ flutter config --android-sdk /usr/local/share/android-sdk
```

### Step-2

Add android-license to flutter

```
$ flutter doctor --android-licenses
```

### Step-3

Check if it works

```
$ flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel master, v1.3.3-pre.18, on Mac OS X 10.14.3 18D109, locale en-US)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
[✓] iOS toolchain - develop for iOS devices (Xcode 10.1)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.3)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)

• No issues found!
```

Comment: Not sure why but Step 2 : flutter doctor --android-licenses worked. Big Thumbs Up

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Windows your sdk path may be

```
/Users/yourUserName/Library/Android/sdk
```

or if are using linux the path maybe

```
/usr/local/share/android-sdk
```

Or

```
/home/yourUserName/Android/sdk
```

Then Try Executing

```
flutter config --android-sdk <your-android-sdk-path>
```